# How to boost prediction of rare events in a keras entity recognition task?

Tags: python, keras, named-entity-recognition

I am working with a dataset of ~90000 tokens (not huge) and in this dataset only ~600 are labelled with something other than the default (not interesting) label (So, in the IOB format more than 89000 tokens are labelled 'O', the rest is labelled with one of five different categories, I'd like to learn).

I am using a bi-lstm network that performs nicely on a sample data set where the 'interesting' categories are relatively more frequent (some 5000 of 12000 tokens are non-'O').

But when training the same network on my data, the outcome is that practically no non-'O' tokens are predicted - it seems that the rare non-'O'events are just not frequent enough for the NN to give them a chance.

In that situation I was thinking about a custom loss function penalizing missing a non-'O' token more than vice versa (falsely predicting a 'O' as a non-'O').

Are there any other best practices that are recommended? (600 out of 90000 doesn't seem too rare, but still, currently I don't get any non-'O' predictions.)

The model I am using is Adam Atkinson's nice implementation (https://github.com/aatkinson/deep-named-entity-recognition) of a keras model which as I said works nicely on a comparable dataset with less rare entities.

Comment: since this is mostly a suggestion, and I am unsure if literature supports the idea I will add as a comment. It is clear that you have way too many 'O' label values. My suggestion would be to scale down the 'O' randomly to the size of your other variables and use the `model.fit_generator()` to randomly select from the dataset during each epoch.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.